# Glossaries package and hyphenated (dashed) acronym fail to break across lines

Tags: line-breaking, glossaries, hyphenation

With respect to using the `glossaries` package, if I have an acronym with a long hyphenated word, it often result in sentences that runs into margins. For example:

```
\newacronym[sort=WH]{WH}{Wh}{Wiener-Hammerstein}
```

results in:

[image: Line-breakring does not occur at dashes]

I have also tried

```
\newacronym[sort=WH]{WH}{Wh}{Wiener\-Hammerstein}
```

But that fails as well, it just produces `WienerHammerstein`.

How do I get round this problem and allow the hyphenated ord to break across the hyphen, but always write the hyphen in normal situations?

Comment: How about `Wiener-Hammer\-stein`?

Comment: @cgnieder Oh interesting did not expect it to work. Thanks. I am still baffled at why dashed words in `glossaries` doesn't behave like naked counterparts which allows automatic line breaking where the hyphen is. Hmm..

Anyway it's good enough band aid fix for me now.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `glossaries`. As soon as a word has an explicit hyphen TeX assumes it is _only_ allowed to break there. That's why you have to help, e.g. by inserting an implicit hyphen like in my proposal.

Comment: It never breaks there, it seems to be always together. I have even seen margin as bad as Wiener|-Hamerstein where | is the margin. I need more testing, let me see if I can make a MWE

Comment: I don't know which language you're using but [`babel`'s shorthands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46811/5049) might also help.

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks. I see I was just having bad luck in one particular sentence. Any easy way to make LaTeX to be very aggressive at preserving margins at all costs? Do I just set `\tolerance` to a really high value?

Comment: In the log file, latex complains about an overfull hbox, right? There you can also see which hyphenation options latex sees at this point. Are they OK?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is not related to [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries). As soon as a word has an explicit hyphen TeX assumes it is only allowed to break there. A quick solution would be

```
\newacronym[sort=WH]{WH}{Wh}{Wiener-Hammer\-stein}
```

that is, adding allowed break points manually.

Another solution would be to use [`babel` shorthands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46811/5049).